# Python sklearn.mixture.GMM not robust to scale?

Tags: python, machine-learning, gaussian, scikit-learn

I'm using [sklearn.mixture.GMM](http://scikit-learn.org/0.11/modules/generated/sklearn.mixture.GMM.html) in Python, and the results seem to depend on data scaling. In the following code example, I change the overall scaling but I do NOT change the relative scaling of the dimensions. Yet under the three different scaling settings I get completely different results:

```
from sklearn.mixture import GMM
from numpy import array, shape
from numpy.random import randn
from random import choice

# centroids will be normally-distributed around zero:
truelumps = randn(20, 5) * 10

# data randomly sampled from the centroids:
data = array([choice(truelumps) + randn(5) for _ in xrange(1000)])

for scaler in [0.01, 1, 100]:
    scdata = data * scaler
    thegmm = GMM(n_components=10)
    thegmm.fit(scdata, n_iter=1000)
    ll = thegmm.score(scdata)
    print sum(ll)
```

Here's the output I get:

```
GMM(cvtype='diag', n_components=10)
7094.87886779
GMM(cvtype='diag', n_components=10)
-14681.566456
GMM(cvtype='diag', n_components=10)
-37576.4496656
```

In principle, I don't think the overall data scaling should matter, and the total log-likelihoods should come out similar each time. But maybe there's an implementation issue I'm overlooking?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I've had [an answer via the scikit-learn mailing list](http://sourceforge.net/mailarchive/forum.php?thread_name=50914D1F.4020708%40inria.fr&forum_name=scikit-learn-general): in my code example, the log-likelihood **should** indeed vary with scale (because we're evaluating point likelihoods, not integrals), by a factor relating to `log(scale)`. So I think my code example in fact shows GMM giving correct results.

Comment: I am hitting the same issue here and am trying to understand. Maybe this sentence from that thread is something to consider 'In general it's
good to mean-center and normalize everything before fitting a mixture
model.' I did not understand why in my model I get one responsibility very close to 1, and the rest almost zero, then I looked at the log probabilities and logsumexp resturns one column because others are very negative.

Answer (score 2):

I think GMM is scale dependent (as is k-means for instance), hence it's recommended to standardize the input as explained in [the preprocessing chapter of the documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html).

Comment: But why? The idea of maximum-likelihood GMM fitting is to find a distribution GMM which maximises the likelihood of the data. Since the three cases in my code differ only in overall scale, the difference in likelihoods should not occur.

Standardising the input certainly makes a difference if it changes the relationship between the dimensions, but my code rescales all the dimensions by the same amount.

Comment: I appreciate if you know why when using predict_proba with GMM I may get almost 1 for one class, and near 0 for the rest? I also used preprocessing on the entire model but it did not help either. It seems this happens regardless of where the test falls regarding the clusters.

Comment: How many features do you have? Maybe you are suffering from the curse of dimensionality. You can try to reduce the dimensionality with `RandomizedPCA` and see if the probabilities are more smooth.

Comment: @ogrisel Thanks, I actually start with a high dimension (more than 100) but after PCA and LDA it gets to only 3 features per-class (say for 10 classes) while I have about 100 samples from each class. GMM only sees the reduced dimension. Also when I draw ellipsoids of the covariance matrix (around their means), the clusters are fairly separate.